# Apache2 not running a python script

Tags: apache, scripting, webserver, cgi

I am very new to webservers and I am learning everything from scratch.

My webpage is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body style="background-color:black;color:white">
<p> My website test site</p>
<br>
<form action="hello.py">
First Name:
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last Name:
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton">
<br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My remote server works, I have gone into my apache2.conf file and tried to change the configuration file so that apache2 will run python scripts:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

The script is found and then instead of running the script, the script is displayed as a text file in the browser. I am trying to run this program remotely from a webpage. I understand right now the output will go to my console.

Comment: What's the apache version, and did you enable mod_cgi? LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

Comment: Also, the apache cgi tutorial covers all issues you can run into while running basic cgi scripts http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html. You should read it to make sure you understand all pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

THanks, I added these changes. Plus I needed to restart the server!